# Error inflating class ImageButton The app crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm making a small card game at the moment and for some reason anytime I try to open my second Activity, it crashes. With the error being the one mentioned in the title.

I tried various ways and unfortunately it always gives me this error.

This is my latest code:

```
package com.example.juegocartas3;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<Cartas> barajaCartas = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random;
    Iterator itr = barajaCartas.iterator();
    public Adapter(@NonNull Context context, int idLayout, @NonNull ArrayList<Cartas> objects) {
        super(context, idLayout, objects);
        barajaCartas = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_items, null);
        ImageButton carta = v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        carta.setImageResource(barajaCartas.get(position).getImagenCarta());
        carta.setTag(barajaCartas.get(position).getPuntaje());

        return v;
    }
}
```

And it says the error is in this line:

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_items, null);
```

And it doesn't make sense to me.

This are the rest of my classes that have to do with the Adapter

```
package com.example.juegocartas3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView tablero;
    ArrayList<Cartas> barajaCartas = new ArrayList<>();

    /*ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<>();*/

    Random random;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        tablero = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.contenedorGrid);
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.asdecopas,1));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.asdeespadas,1));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.caballodebastos,11));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.caballodeespadas,11));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.dosdecopas,2));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.reydecopas,12));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.sotadeespadas,10));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.sotadeoros,0));
        barajaCartas.add(new Cartas(this,R.drawable.tresbastos,3));

        Adapter myAdapter = new Adapter (this,R.layout.grid_view_items,barajaCartas);
        tablero.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Collections.shuffle(barajaCartas);

    }

    public void onClickCarta(View v) {

    }

}
```

My class of cards:

```
package com.example.juegocartas3;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class Cartas extends ImageButton {

    @DrawableRes
    int imagenCarta;
    int puntaje;

    public Cartas(Context context,@DrawableRes int imagenCarta, int puntaje) {
        super(context);
        this.imagenCarta = imagenCarta;
        this.puntaje=puntaje;

    }
    @DrawableRes
    public int getImagenCarta(){
        return imagenCarta;
    }

    public void setImagenCarta() {
        this.imagenCarta = imagenCarta;
    }

    public int getPuntaje() {
        return puntaje;
    }

    public void setPuntaje(int puntaje) {
        this.puntaje = puntaje;
    }
}
```

And the two xml (the second one being the one I wish to stick on the first):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:id="@+id/contenedorGrid"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_items">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/trasera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClickCarta"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe it's too much to ask but is something wrong with any of these classes?
Or should I do things a different way?

Edit: This is the error text:

> 2022-05-25 18:24:23.107 2988-2988/com.example.juegocartas3
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageButton
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
> at com.example.juegocartas3.Adapter.getView(Adapter.java:41)
> at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
> at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:496)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):
> TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700a5 a=-1 r=0x7f0700a5}
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1897)
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
> at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:120)
> at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:87)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:78)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:226)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.create

And this line is the one I was referring to earlier:

> at com.example.juegocartas3.Adapter.getView(Adapter.java:41)

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_items, null);
```

Comment: Look into logcat for error massage.

Comment: @Jens is correct - you need to post the specific error message from your logcat

Comment: what is `@drawable/trasera`, specifically?  It seems unhappy about that.

Comment: @RyanM it's the first background image of the button. When I want to click on it(the Image Button), it will change to another picture. I still didn't make the onClickListener.

Comment: No, I mean what is in that file?  I suspect it's related based on the error.

Comment: @RyanM it's a png image.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_items, null);
```

with

```
View v = getApplicationContext().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_view_items, null);
```

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it gives me an error, telling me to create the method. I've looked it up and from what I've seen there shouldn't be this error since I have a constructor with super(context) in the same class.

Comment: can you please tell if the error got resolved, if yes, please give fix which worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you do not have your drawable files for your cards in the proper drawable folder based on the API level you are running. For example, if the files are in `/drawable-26`, when you run your app on API 25 that would be the error you would get.

If the drawables for your cards are not specific to an API level, move them to the `/drawable` folder.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment if you've seen it. I checked again and they were actually in drawable-24. Thank you for this.

Comment: It did not work. It's still crashing. My previous comment was probably misleading. Sorry about that.

Comment: I still think it is related to the drawable folder issue. Try temporarily moving all of them to /drawables folder and see if that works.